# Expander and list view item behavior?

Tags: c#, wpf

See this picture:

[image]

When you click and listbox item inside a expander its keep select until you pick another item of the same list, if you have a click event it won't trigger unless you change from item in the same list.

Any Help Please.

```
<Grid HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="420" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="214">
    <ScrollViewer HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="420" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="214">
        <Grid>
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <TreeView Grid.Row="0" Name="treeView1" />
            <Expander Grid.Row="1" Header="expander1" Name="expander1" IsExpanded="False">
                <ListBox>
                    <ListBoxItem Content="Unit 1"/>
                    <ListBoxItem Content="Unit 2"/>
                </ListBox>
            </Expander>
            <Expander Grid.Row="2" Header="expander2" Name="expander2" IsExpanded="False">
                <ListBox>
                    <ListBoxItem Content="Unit 1"/>
                    <ListBoxItem Content="Unit 2"/>
                </ListBox>
            </Expander>
        </Grid>
```

This code is a copy just to explain the problem in the picture.

Comment: How can we help if your Question doesn't have a "?" this a a affirmation or a question? Please be clear

Comment: done, now can you help me?

Comment: I re-read your publication very willingly and still don't understand your question.

Comment: did you watch the picture?

Comment: the firts item you click on a list keep click until you click another item in the same list, so if you click another item in another list you can't go back and click the firts item you click at the firts list its wont work because its allready clicket.

Answer (score 1):

```
<Expander Grid.Row="1" Header="expander1" Name="expander1" IsExpanded="False">
                        <ListBox>
                            <ListBoxItem Content="Unit 1" PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown="ListBoxItem_PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown"/>
                            <ListBoxItem Content="Unit 2"/>
                        </ListBox>
                    </Expander>
                    <Expander Grid.Row="2" Header="expander2" Name="expander2" IsExpanded="False">
                        <ListBox>
                            <ListBoxItem Content="Unit 1"/>
                            <ListBoxItem Content="Unit 2" x:Name="listitem1"/>
                        </ListBox>
                    </Expander>
```

and the CS look like this.

```
private void ListBoxItem_PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
        {
            listitem1.IsSelected = false;
        }
```

now the item on the other list go back to normal no selected.